# Change detection with Observable vs Immutable

Tags: angular

So I read [this article](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2) about Angular 2 change detection, but after reading it I have got more confused, so I started reading some of the comments which led to more confusion.

### Immutable Objects

> If a component depends only on its input properties, and they are
>   immutable, then this component can change if and only if one of its
>   input properties changes. Therefore, we can skip the component’s subtree in the change detection tree until such an event occurs. When it happens, we can check the subtree once, and then disable it until the next change (gray boxes indicate disabled change detectors).

So if **{{todo.text}}** or **todo.checked** change we *mark* our **todo:Todo** that a changed has occurred
[image: Immutable objects]

But then from my understanding, we can create a cascade of immutable objects.

> If we are aggressive about using immutable objects, a big chunk of the
>   change detection tree will be disabled most of the time.

[image: cascade immutable obejcts]

```
@Component({changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush})
class ImmutableTodoCmp {
  todo:Todo;
}
```

So in this case, any changes on **{{todo.text}}** or **todo.checked** won't be noticed right? only when a Todo is pushed we will see a change?

### Observable Objects

> If a component depends only on its input properties, and they are observable, then this component can change if and only if one of its input properties emits an event. Therefore, we can skip the component’s subtree in the change detection tree until such an event occurs. When it happens, we can check the subtree once, and then disable it until the next change.
>
> Although it may sound similar to the Immutable Objects case, it is quite different. If you have a tree of components with immutable bindings, a change has to go through all the components starting from the root. This is not the case when dealing with observables.

I don't get it how Observables are quite different from Immutables and in this specific case of the Todo app, which approach is better?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So, like we are 5 year olds from now on.

This is `JohnCmp`. John is a component that accepts *two* inputs, a `name: {first: 'John', last: 'Smith'}` and an `age: 20`.

What happens if `name` is mutable? Well, someone could pass it to `John` and hold a reference to it. So that John, and **ANY** number of other objects or services can hold a reference to that `name` object. This means they can change it, say doing `name.last = 'foo'`. And John's **name changes** now, but he didn't receive a **new** name. He still has a reference to that `name` object, but it mutated.

If we want to **detect** this, we have to **aggressively** check **name**, **name.first**, **name.last**, and so on with **every property of every object we pass around**. How much easier would it be to do `name === newName` and just compare references, hey? **If name is immutable, we don't need to go crazy and check every property, we can check references and know if an object is changed quickly**.

Ok, now, imagine nobody holds a reference to `John`'s **name** object. So if they want to give him a new name, they must pass in a **NEW** name object. Then `John` changes **only** when his **input** changes. This is what is meant here:

> If a component depends only on its input properties, and they are immutable, then this component can change if and only if one of its input properties changes. Therefore, we can skip the component’s subtree in the change detection tree until such an event occurs.

Alright, so that's the basic case right? Now **we don't have to worry about checking every property**, we just check that **references haven't changed**. Much improved! BUT objects can be large. So a `people` array is an immutable `Array` of `John`s, which are immutable, of `name`s that are also immutable. So in order to change John's name. you need to produce a **new** name, and a **new** John, and a **new** people array.

So they all change, the whole tree needs to be traversed. So that's `O(n)`. Hence this little comment:

> If you have a tree of components with immutable bindings, a change has to go through all the components starting from the root.

BUT

> This is not the case when dealing with observables.

**Why tho?**

Observables emit events. They don't need to change everything like immutables, they just need to `emit` a change event. So in his example, you don't have an immutable "array" that you need to recreate and therefore re-evaluate all the changes up the tree. Now you have a `people` observable, that triggers events when it changes. And `John` receives an observable as well.

So you can just trigger an event in `John` telling him that his name changed, WITHOUT triggering an event in `people` or things of the sort. Avoiding you to re scan everything for changes, thus reducing complexity to `O(log n)`, as per this quote:

> As you can see, here the Todos component has only a reference to an observable of an array of todos. **So it cannot see the changes in individual todos**.

(emphasis mine).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

> I don't get it how Observables are quite different from Immutables and in this specific case of the Todo app, which approach is better?

Imagine that you have a tree of nodes, and each node has a bit that says *"I may have changed"*. With `Observable`, we are talking about [events getting emitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit); the event is dispatched **up the tree**. In other words:

- `Todo_ChangeDetector` would be flagged,
- then walking up the tree, `Todos_ChangeDetector` would be flagged,
- then walking up the tree, `App_ChangeDetector` would be flagged,
- then **the normal change detection kicks in**.

Imagine you have 2 todo lists:

1. a grocery list.
2. a list of meetings (work?) for the day.

Which grocery list is active you are currently showing would be the `Observable`; e.g. a dropdown, nav pills, etc. All the todo items under those 2 lists could be `Immutable`; e.g. you are not the meeting organizer and cannot change the meetings.