# Change detection Angular1 vs Angular2 (Confusion)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular5

**AngularJs(1.x)** : So far my understanding of change detection in Angularjs(1.x) , watchers gets added to watch list , and whenever any event occurs , Digest cycle triggers , that is checking of watchers "**starting from rootscope**". So first parent scope watchers will be checked and then chld scope. And digest Cycle always triggers from rootscope whenever any user event or async operation happens.Is that correct?

**Angular2+:**

So here they are saying , change detection always runs once and it will be always unidirectional flow of change(parent-to-child). How? I can pass object from parent and change it in child , so how come unidirectional?

And also , how change ditection in angularjs(1.x) is a graph? Cause every time it will start from rootscope watchers ,irrespective of whatever scope value changed?

Dont really get how angularjs has Graph structure and Angular2+ has tree?

Please clear my doubt...

Comment: Have a Look at [Change Detection Reinvented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvKGQSFQf10&t=644s) and [Angular 2 Change Detection Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxD91DWkGM)

Comment: See [Change detection with Observable vs Immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313661/change-detection-with-observable-vs-immutable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Angular 2 change detection work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469024/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-work).